# str_replace within foreach php not working

Tags: php, curl, replace

My code runs fine, but `str_replace $p` page number does not change or increase.

I tried `$n` as in the `str_replace` variable it returned 6 for all and `$p` returned 1 for all and tried to put `$n` or `$p` in {}

```
$n = 6;
$start = range(1, $n);
foreach ($start as &$p) {
$url = str_replace("page-", "page-$p", $url);

#curlexe, etc
}
```

I did read https://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3001.htm but it wasn't much help for me.

Comment: Overwriting `$url` is probably [not what you want](https://3v4l.org/WFW0P). Instead I’m guessing you want to [keep the original](https://3v4l.org/RoM2q) as a template for a temporary/local one. Also, unless you have a specific need for it, avoid `&` with variables

Comment: thank u it worked. itwas one of those cases wherei p spend hours on something being caught in a loop and forgetting to look outside again. thank you so much.  Chris Haas

Comment: question within my foraeach there is a curl then another foreach with a curl. when ever the second curl is executed the foreach parent loop stops... any tips? the second curl has a different name..

Answer (score 1):

You're seemingly reusing the URL generated in previous iteration for the next one, so you're making replacements in a string that grows as the loop goes on:

```
https://example.com/page-
https://example.com/page-1
https://example.com/page-21
https://example.com/page-321
https://example.com/page-4321
https://example.com/page-54321
https://example.com/page-654321
```

Instead:

```
$template = 'https://example.com/page-';
$n = 6;
$start = range(1, $n);
foreach ($start as $p) {
    $url = str_replace("page-", "page-$p", $template);
}
```

But you probably don't even need to replace anything in the fist place, just build the URL you want at once:

```
foreach ($start as $p) {
    $url = "https://example.com/page-$p";
}
```

You may have noticed I've removed the [`&` reference operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). I can't imagine what use it can possibly have here.